# Redirection based on current time

Tags: javascript, html

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
```

I am getting correct time.
want to convert date and time in IST too.

and I want to redirect to new url based on time

if current IST time is

```
6:00 PM IST
```

I want to redirect website user after 2 hours.

Like after 8:00 PM IST

```
top.location.href = 'xxxxx';
```

Comment: Please reformat your question.

Comment: maybe try `window.setTimeout(func, milis)`, that will call some function after defined amount of miliseconds.

Comment: You want a different redirection every 2 hours? for example, 6.00, 8.00, 10.00... ?

Comment: no just once. only after 2 hours

Comment: Ok, and you want this to happen if the user has stayed on the same page for 2 hours? For example a user starts looking at the page at 15:00 then the redirect happens at 17:00?

Comment: no according to current time

Comment: What you have described in your question is completely different from what you want based on the comments. Please can you be more clear on your requirements so that you may get the help you need? Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
},7200000);
```

This should work, this example should redirect to google.com after 7200000 milliseconds ( 2 hours).

Try around with it.... Change the location to the URL you want and you can change 7200000 to 3000 for testing purposes.